# How can do multible selected value alert onchange?

Tags: jquery, html

I think about recording information from right to left or vice versa in the database

```js
this.init = function() {
    var pickListHtml =
      "<div class='row'>" +
      "  <div class='col-sm-5'>" +
      " <h1>Atanmamis Kullanicilar</h1>" +
      "  <select class='form-control pickListSelect pickData' multiple><option data-id='2'>aziz</option></select>" +
      " </div>" +
      " <div class='col-sm-2 pickListButtons'>" +
      " <button type='button' class='pAdd btn btn-primary btn-sm'>" + opts.add + "</button>" +
      "      <button type='button'  class='pAddAll btn btn-primary btn-sm'>" + opts.remove + "</button>" +
      " <button type='button' class='pRemove btn btn-primary btn-sm'>" + opts.addAll + "</button>" +
      " <button type='button' class='pRemoveAll btn btn-primary btn-sm'>" + opts.removeAll + "</button>" +
      " </div>" +
      " <div class='col-sm-5'>" +
      " <h4>'Atanmis Kullanicilar'</h4>" +
      "    <select onchange='tester()' class='form-control pickListSelect pickListResult' id='pickListResult' multiple><option
    data - id = '22' > kartas < /option></select > " +
    " </div>" +
    "</div>";
    this.html(pickListHtml);
```

I am adding with jQuery but how do I write a method to change it?

```
function tester() {
  select = $('#pickListResult');
  selected = new Array();
  ////////i have no idea
  alert(selected);
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/filadown/8ek53b1f/show)**

Comment: first of in your jquery your `pickListResult` is a class not an id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bit unclear what you want your `selected` to contain, but you can do it like this.

```
function tester(obj) {
  var select = $(obj); // select is now equal to the select your changed.

  selected = select.find(":selected").toArray() // will return the options you have selected

  console.log(selected);
}
```

This will return the elements that are selected in your select

Note to make it work your `onchange` need `this` like `onchange='tester(this)'`

**Demo**

```js
function tester(obj) {
  var select = $(obj);

  var selected = select.find(":selected").toArray()

  console.log(selected);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange='tester(this)' class='form-control pickListSelect pickListResult' multiple>
  <option>test1</option>
  <option>test2</option>
  <option>test3</option>
  <option>test4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Vaav :). Thank you so much.

Comment: When button is clicked, new element is added but how can I do this when the content of the table changes?